# Modifying ASPX.CS file has no effect

Tags: asp.net, exception, caching, iis, code-behind

One of my colleagues maintains a legacy ASP.NET site. Today she bumped into a strange problem:

1. There is an ASPX page, which throws an exception.
2. If she *deletes* the line of the ASPX.CS file which throws the exception, the exception remains (with the same call stack). I'm sure she modified the very same file the calls stack refers to.
3. If she renames the ASPX.CS file, the server says the file is missing.
4. If she restarts the server after modifying the ASPX.CS, the exception remains.
5. If she modifies other ASPX.CS files, she gets the expected effect.
6. She doesn't compile the page into DLL.

AFAIK IIS should recompile the file when its content changes ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723)), but this mechanism doesn't work in this case. What should we do? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the website is a website or web application. Web applications compile all the code behind into DLLs and place them into the 'bin' folder. In order to make changes to the code available, you would have to 'build' the application in VS.

If it is not a compiled web application, then she should check to see if the front end page is pointing to the correct code behind page. Sometimes if you manually copy and rename files, this piece could be left pointing to the original page, not the new .cs file.

Comment: She doesn't compile this ASPX.CS into DLL, so I think IIS compiles it. AFAIK IIS should recompile it after modification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723 This works in case of other pages, but doesn't work for this file.

Comment: While she may not have to compile the whole site, perhaps this one page was compiled and the DLL was added to the project. Check the bin folder for a DLL named similarly to that file. If it is not there, try removing all code from the code behind and put in a few events in load such as response.clear, response.write("test"), and response.end to see if that event is getting fired.